# dropdown field is not correctly when page is reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a product page form with 2 field country and city.
https://jsfiddle.net/pc6a8m06/2/

Selecting country will change the city list.

When I submit the form, the country (ex: Úc) and city (ex:Sydney) data are sent to server.

However, when I re-open the product page form for editing purpose, only country name (Úc) is shown correctly. The city field is set to default.
[image]

1. Is there any way to fix my javascript code so that the city field shows "Sydney" instead of empty selection (due to `dep.empty().append('<option>-Chọn TP-</option>');` )
2. When the product page form is load,i havent clicked to select countries yet, it means  `dep.empty().append('<option>-Chọn TP-</option>');` has not called yet. Why does i lost the value "Sydney" of city field?

Comment: Show the complete code

Answer (score 1):

The first part of populating the cities is easy enough...just trigger the change event on the countries select when page loads and after you bind the event handler

```
$('[name="departure_country[]"]').change(function(e){
      // code to populate cities  here

// now trigger the change
}).change();
```

Then set the value of the city from whatever your data source is

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you post the form data, your client state ( jquery ) would reset. In order to set it after the post, you need to execute the same script again, not wait for on change.

```
var cities = {

  "Úc": [{
    display: "Canberra",
    value: "Canberra"
  }, {
    display: "Sydney",
    value: "Sydney"
  }, {
    display: "Melbourne",
    value: "Melbourne"
  }, {
    display: "Perth",
    value: "Perth"
  }, {
    display: "Gold Coast ",
    value: "Gold-Coast"
  }],

  "Pháp": [{
    display: "Paris",
    value: "Paris"
  }, {
    display: "Avignon",
    value: "Avignon"
  }, {
    display: "Strasbourg",
    value: "Strasbourg"
  }, {
    display: "Nice",
    value: "Nice"
  }],

  "Nhật Bản": [{
    display: "Tokyo",
    value: "Tokyo"
  }, {
    display: "Osaka",
    value: "Osaka"
  }]
};

(function($) {

  $('[name="departure_country[]"]').change(function(){
        var $this = this;
        SetCity($this);
    });

  function SetCity(obj)
  {    
      var country = $(obj).val();

      var clist = cities[country];

      var dep = $('[name="departure[]"]');

      dep.empty().append('<option>--select--</option>');

      $(clist).each(
        function(i, v) {
          $('<option>').text(v.display).val(v.value).appendTo(dep);
        }
      );       
  }

  SetCity();


})(jQuery);
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/pc6a8m06/4/